# getters is always return true in vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

The `isLoggedIn` in getters is always true event if there is no token from API i can stil go to every routes i don't know what is the error in guard route or i'm storing token wrong in state. in this statement is not working if(`!store.getters.isLoggedIn`){ go to login}
plz help me I'm stuck :(

in store.js

```
state:{
    Token: localStorage.getItem('access_token') || null,
}
mutations:{
    AUTHENTICATION(state,token){
        state.Token = token;
    },
    UNAUTHENTICATION(state,response){
        state.Token = response;
    }
},
getters:{
    isLoggedIn(state){
        return state.Token !=null;
    }
},
actions:{
    loginUser({commit}, formData){                
          http.post("/login",formData).then((response)=>{
                if(response.data.status === 'success'){
                    const token = response.data.token;
                    localStorage.setItem('access_token',token);
                    localStorage.setItem('user',response.data.user);
                    commit('AUTHENTICATION',token);                         
                    router.push({name:'Dashboard'});
                    router.go();
                }else{
                    commit("LOGIN_ERROR",response.data.message);
                }
            })
            .catch((error)=>{
                if(error){
                    commit('UNAUTHENTICATION',null);                        
                    localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
                    commit("GET_ERRORS",error.response.data.errors);
                }
            });
        });
    },
    logoutUser({commit}){
        http.post("/auth/logout").then((response)=>{
            if(response.data.status === "success"){
                localStorage.clear();
                commit('UNAUTHENTICATION',null);
                router.push({name:'Login'});
                window.location.reload();
            }else{
                commit("LOGIN_ERROR",response.data.message);
            }
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            if(error){
                commit("GET_ERRORS",error.response.data.errors);
            }
        });
    }
},
```

in route.js

```
route.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);
    if(requiresAuth){ 
        if(!store.getters.isLoggedIn){
            next({name: 'Login'}); 
        }else{
            next();
        }
    }else{
        next();
    }
});
```

Comment: try console.log(state.Token) in getter make sure data

Comment: The token is still there but it still not working :( how i'm i suppose to do i'm stuck almost a week.

Answer (score 0):

while there is no `access_token` in your local storage then `localStorage.getItem('access_token')` will return the value `undefined` which is not equal to null in **non-strict not version** `!=` so you getter will be always true
instead, you should use (**strict not version**) or (**double not version** ): 
**option 1 :**

```js
getters:{
    isLoggedIn(state){
        return state.Token !== null; //double equals
    }
}
```

**option 2 :**

```js
getters:{
    isLoggedIn(state){
        return !!state.Token; // double !
    }
}
```

Comment: not working :( .

Comment: the result of !store.getters.isLoggedIn is alway return false what does that mean?